# As Megabeth, on what Endorsements and Products should I focus?

Tags: super-monday-night-combat

The title states the Question.
I just bought myself permanent access to Megabeth, leaving me with the Question which Endorsements and Products would be the best setup for agressive but supportive Gameplay within this game.

As explanation: 
I love to kill many bots but also engage players directly as I encounter them. My main concern is, as with other moba games, survival and kills.

For now I equipped only some health and heals upon juicing to make up for missing skill while still learning the game, but I am sure there are better solutions.

**As Megabeth, on what Endorsements and Products should I focus?**

Answer (score 1):

Reload speed and fire-rate are nice and +12.5% clip size will gain you an additional rocket.

As for products if you're going after bots then the clear choice would be the bot buster. If you find that you're not in range constantly for looting you could go with the Money Magnet.